# .LOAD is Replacing everything inside my DIV

Tags: jquery, html, load

I know that Jquery.LOAD is supposed to replace all the content of a div, but can I perhaps .append a page instead of .load a page (or some function like .append where I can load an external page inside a div)?  I have some headers than I don't want replaced that reside in said div.

Right now I am using the onClose event in a Fancybox to load a page back into a div with the class "heriyah", how could I use that with .get, .ajax, or some other function??

**EDIT:** Okay, so I added this to my fancybox, and it appears that append is not going to work after all because it adds to what is already loaded rather than refreshing the DIV. Sorry if this is confusing, but I have PHP looping through the database and making appends for the data, so I want the data to be refreshed on Fancybox close which works with .load, but that deletes my content headers already in the DOM (which is weird).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `append` with Jquery `get`,

```
 $.get("URL",null,function (data){
          $('#content') .html(data);      
     });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

EDIT,

Then place the content in another sub div and replace it like this,

```
<div id="yourDiv">
//your headers here..
   <div id="content">

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Okay, so I added this to my fancybox, and it appears that append is not going to work after all because it adds to what is already loaded rather than refreshing the DIV.  Sorry if this is confusing, but I have PHP looping through the database and making appends for the data, so I want the data to be refreshed on Fancybox close which works with .load, but that deletes my content headers already in the DOM (which is weird).

Comment: I really don't want to have to do that, but I will say this: Your code worked, the only this is it doubled what I had already had in my DIV.  On pageload, I .load page.php into my DOM.  Then I refresh that from Fancybox, but when I use .get it just doubles everything.

Comment: Did you use `.html()` function. It should replace the content !

Comment: I didn't use HTML, but I fixed the problem by just rearranging my divs

Answer (score 1):

you can just use the plain `AJAX` requests like [`$.get`<sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), [`$.post`<sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), and [`$.ajax`<sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.get(url, data, function (data, status, xhr) {
  $(...selector...).append(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    dataType:"html",
    type:"GET",
    url:"/url",
    success:function(data){
        $("#divID").append(data);
    },
    error:function(jxhr){
        if(typeof(console)!='undefined'){
            console.log(jxhr.responseText);
        }
    }
});
```

`.load` is just the shorthand for `ajax`

Answer (score 0):

If you want clear div before append

```
$.get("URL",null,function (data){
           $('#yourDiv') .html("");          
          $('#yourDiv') .append(data);      
     });
```